# Problem with FourSquare API calling after OAuth in iOS

Tags: ios4, oauth, foursquare

I am facing this problem while trying to use FourSquare API with iPhone.

I am doing OAuth initially for getting tokens. So, now I have my application's client id & client secret. And oauth token & oauth token secret for the user. I am using this:

```
https://github.com/jdg/oauthconsumer
```

However, I am not sure how to proceed from here to calling the APIs. I mean, if I do this -

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues.json?geolat=-78.695548&geolong=35.767138&l=10&oauth_token=OAUTH_TOKEN
```

I am getting this reply:

```
{"meta":{"code":401,"errorType":"invalid_auth","errorDetail":"OAuth token not found or has been revoked."},"response":{}}
```

Can anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong here ?

Thanks.

-
ahsan

Answer (score 1):

Please try this sample code and intgrate it in your code to get the correct access token

https://github.com/drewvergara/Foursquare-OAuth-iPhone